# Wait for callback result before exiting the method

Tags: c#, callback, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have following code to check valid FingerPrint on app launch. I am using Xamarin.Forms.

**PlatformSpecific (Xamarin.iOS)**

```
public bool IsValidTouchID()
        {

    var replyHandler = new LAContextReplyHandler((success, er) =>
                            {

                                if (success)
                                {
                                    isSuccess = true;

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    isSuccess = false;
                                }

                            });
  context.EvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, "Enter Touch ID", replyHandler);

  return isSuccess;

 }
```

Based on `replyHandler` I have to navigate to different page. Since it is a callback function first it returning the method and then calling `replyHandler`. Hence always `False` is returned.

I tried async, await but I couldn't achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a TaskCompletionSource:

```
public Task<bool> IsValidTouchIDAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    var replyHandler = new LAContextReplyHandler((success, er) => tcs.SetResult(success);

    context.EvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, "Enter Touch ID", replyHandler);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Note that the method is now asynchronous, so the caller must await it.

Comment: Thanks. But above code not showing TouchID alert screen which is used to get fingerprint input. So even now always False is returned

Comment: @Subha Was your original code showing the TouchID alert screen? Because I haven't changed this part...

Comment: Yes, my original code was showing alert and even validated also, but above code not showing any alert and always giving false without getting FingerPrint input.

Comment: @Subha Then I can't really help you. I haven't changed the TouchID code, and unfortunately I don't know how it works.